# New to Python - Issue with print function

Tags: python, oop

Excuse me for a very basic question, but I am very new to Python. 
Below is a sample code where I am trying to print a car speed.. the print function however does not seem to give output in the desired format. Please see below.

```
class car:

    def __init__(self,year,speed):
        self.speed = speed
        self.year = year

    def getSpeed(self):
        print("Speed is: ",self.speed)

BMW = car(2016, 150)
BMW.getSpeed()
```

Output:

```
$python main.py
('Speed is: ', 150)
```

I am expecting the output to be printed without brackets and quotes like below:

```
Speed is: 150
```

Comment: That is python2, so try ` print "Speed is: ",self.speed`. But i strongly suggest you to use string formatting. So ` print("Speed is: {}".format(self.speed))`. Happy learning :)

Comment: When i run that code in python 3 the ouput is `Speed is:  150`, just as you want.

Comment: @Cleared. You re using python3 then :)

Comment: Thank you @han solo.. it worked

Comment: You have a few options, here are 3 of them:

    - use python3 and you can call `print("Speed is", self.speed)`
    - use python2 but call `print("Speed is: {}".format(self.speed))`
    - use python2 but call `print("Speed is: %d" % (self.speed,))`

Comment: As it seems you are learning some OOP I would suggest that you also treat the value as a class attribute: `print ("Speed is: {}".format(BMW.speed))`. Just make sure to add this code outside the class definition.